# What's the best way to serialize an array and pass it through the get method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, history.js

So I'm using an ajax request to pass some data for filtering purposes.

Then I use history.js so I can change the url and add a state to the browser, making it possible to go back, go forward etc. This way, I can filter my data with an ajax request or a normal request. So far so good.

My problem is, in the data I pass through the ajax request there is an array:

```
function updateContent(url, state) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {name: state.filter_name, num: state.filter_number, 
            data: state.filter_data, array: state.filter_array},
        url: url,
        success: function(msg) {
                $('#ajax').html(msg);
        }
    }); 
    
}
```

This will make a request to this URL:

```
http: //localhost/Project/Controller/?filter_array%5B%5D=1&filter_array%5B%5D=50&filter_array%5B%5D=70.
```

And I want to pass this url to the history.pushstate

If I use jsenconde then build manually the url, the url will be slighter different, will be something like:

```
http://localhost/Project/Controller/?filter_array=["1","50","70"]
```

Although it's more cleaner, I read somewhere that you shouldn't use [] in url's but even if I use this way I will get two types of GET url's, the ajax URL ?`filter_array%5B%5D=1&filter_array%5B%5D=50&filter_array%5B%5D=70.` and the json url `?filter_array=["1","50","70"]`.

So I just need a solution that get's me just one type of GET url, so I can use the same url to ajax, and normal requests.

Comment: There is nothing *wrong* with using `[]` in URLs, it's just not natively compatible with anything other than PHP. But if what you are bothered about here is [`history.pushstate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState().C2.A0method), why not just store the data in the `stateObj` and examine this instead of the URL when you get a state pop event? That way you can use a PHP-friendly URL and still have easy access to your data in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to pass an array of values is to pass the name with `[]`'s repeatedly (url-encoded) as in your first example.

You need to generate your URL in such a way that it complies with this...

```
filter_array[]=1&filter_array[]=2&filter_array[]=3
```

which, of course, encodes as you showed....

```
filter_array%5B%5D=1&filter_array%5B%5D=2&filter_array%5B%5D=3
```

If you stick with this format, your code will be more portable (eg ASP.Net will perform the conversion to List automatically as will many PHP libraries).

Is there any reason you can't generate the url in this format?

The difference here is that one is using standard forms encoding, the other is converting JSON

Comment: `[]` is not *the* standard way - it's not even *a* standard way, it's just the way PHP does it.

Comment: @DaveRandom PHP, ASP.Net and RoR all support it. I admit I don't know about others so will accept it might not be *the* standard but it's definitely *a* standard and it works.

Comment: Oh it definitely works and is supported by many systems, but just be wary of making "this is *the* standard" remarks when you can't reference an RFC, is my point. A lack of a standard breeds creative implementation...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is URL encoding the JSON object so that there are no illegal characters. If you want to then retrieve that GET variable using javascript, you will have to pull the data from the URL, URL decode it, then use JSON.parse() to turn it back into a JavaScript object.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp